# Como debo tratar una transición que arranca cuando un Edit text recibe el foco en android studio

Tags: edittext

tengo un actividad que tiene en su parte gráfica un Edit text, he conseguido que al crearla no tenga el foco .
Cuando recibe el foco tiene un una transición que esconde componentes de un menú pero el problema es que cada vez que recibe el foco arranca la transición y solo quería que lo hiciera la primera vez.
Alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas que solo se haga una vez, puedes crear un `flag`, utilizar un `boolean` que cambia de valor cuando se realiza la primera transición. Si no se cumple con la condición, el código que realiza la transición simplemente no se ejecuta.

```
boolean transicionEjecutada = false;

...

if (!transicionEjecutada) {
    realizarTransicion();
}

...

void realizarTransicion() {
    ...
    transicionEjecutada = true;
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Luego intentaré hacer lo que me has dicho a ver si hay suerte!

Comment: Me ha funcionado par lo que quería hacer! Gracias!

Comment: ¡Genial! Me alegro mucho, upvote y mucho éxito con el proyecto.

Comment: No me deja votar aún Elena, creo que no tengo los puntos necesarios!